# how to get content within a specific text from a file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file name demo.txt with content as follows:

```
value -= [
 "02|05|06|abc",
]

/* Some other content other than value variable */

value -= [
]

value -= [
 "0698|06|07|abc",
]
```

I have lots of value variables in this demo.txt file.

I want to print only unique values like below after reading demo.txt file

```
02| 05| 06| 0698| 07| abc
```

I tried as follows:

```
awk '$0 == "value -= [" {i=1;next};i && i++ <= 1'
```

which gives me

```
"02|05|06|abc",
]
"0698|06|07|abc",
```

But, I do not want "]" and also do not want repeated content. In this case its "06" and "abc"

Can some one suggest ?

Comment: does your input file always have values like `"02|05|06|abc",` on separate line? And are the values alone quoted?

Comment: Yes, it always have value like as mentioned in you comment with quotes.

Comment: thanks for clarification, do you also want your output as just unique values or values separated by `|` character?

Comment: Just unique values would be sufficient. Can you help me out ? Thanks

Comment: check my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ grep -oE '".*"' demo.txt | grep -oE '\w+' | sort -u
02
05
06
0698
07
abc
```

- `-o` Print  only  the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line
- `-E` Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression
- `".*"` gets all values within quotes
- `\w+` 1 or more of letters/digits/underscore characters
- `sort -u` to get unique values

Comment: `abc` is missing.

Comment: Yes, because `abc` is duplicated, not because it is not a number.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs I just missed by mistake about `abc`. Basically, We dont know the type of value here. it can be string, integer. `abc` and `06` is duplicate and should be printed only once

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using `awk -v RS='' -F='"' -f script input_file`

```
/value -= \[/ {
    split($0, data);
    count = split(data[2], values, "|");
    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        result[values[i]] = values[i];
    }
}

END {
    for (r in result) {
        printf r "|";
    }
    print "";
}
```

It can also be done with `sed`:

```
sed -nr '/"/{s/[ "]//g;s/,/|/;G;s/\n//;x};${x; :a; s/([^|]+\|)(.*)\1/\2/; ta; p}' input
```

Comment: I did not understand correctly. How can I pass file as input. ?

Comment: `sed` you specified repeats lots of values and it even breaks values. especially strings. `awk` script gives empty output.

Comment: With the data your example provides? It works for me.